# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'

Tags: .net, sqlite, elmah

I've installed ELMAH 1.1 .Net 3.5 x64 in my ASP.NET project and now I'm getting this error (whenever I try to see any page):

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.
>
> Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

More error details at the bottom.

My Active Solution platform is "Any CPU" and I'm running on a x64 Windows 7 on an x64, of course, processor. The reason why we are using this version of ELMAH is because 1.0 .Net 3.5 (x86, which is the only platform for which it's compiled) gave us this same error on our x64 Windows server.

I've tried compiling for x86 and x64 and I get the same error. I've tried removing the all compiler output (bin and obj). Finally I've made a reference to the SQLite dll directly, something that was not needed for the project to work on the server and I've got this compiler error:

> Error 1 Warning as Error: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' targets a different processor MyProject

Any ideas what the problem might be?

More error details:

> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +43
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +127    System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +142    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +613    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean
>   supportLocalization, String
>   outputAssemblyName) +54
>   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +232
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
>   +52    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +337
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +512    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost,
>   IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters) +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8896783
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) +259

Comment: A Fusion (assembly binding) log is much more useful in such cases than this sheet of a stack trace.

Comment: It seems the problem was that Cassini is x86.

Comment: I have had the same issue and had to abandon ELMAH because of the mixed production/development environment we have. Given that using SQLite on a high traffic production web server doesn't sound very good and the fact that SQLite dll is the only assembly in ELMAH that forces it to have two different versions for x86 and 64x bits, I am wondering why ELMAH guys pull it out and make it optional rather than what it is now.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`System.Data.SQLite.dll` is a mixed assembly, i.e. it contains both managed code and native code. Therefore a particular `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is either x86 or x64, but never both.

**Update (*courtesy J. Pablo Fernandez*):** Cassini, the development web server used by Visual Studio when you press F5 or click the green «play» button, is x86 only which means that even if your workstation is x64, you'll only be able to use the x86 version of System.Data.SQLite.dll.

An alternative is not to use Cassini but IIS7 which is properly x64.

Comment: I am using the x64 version on a x64 computer.

Comment: Did you try using the x86 version?

Comment: A new alternative that become available shortly ago is to use IIS Express that allows you to set the type of application pool you want to use

Comment: @Raul Vejar: please elaborate on how application pool selection feature of IIS Express solves the 32-bit/64-bit assembly issue. Thanks

Comment: @Tim, that feature allows you to select the type of application pool you want to use, either 32 or 64 bit, that way you can control that aspect that was fixed in Cassini and work with the same bit library you have. In other words, if you are using the 32 bit version of the SQLite dll, then you should select the 32 bit application pool on IIS Express. For the 64 bit version of the library you should select the 64 bit application pool.

Comment: Are you saying an assembly that isn't mixed can be both x86 and x64?

Answer (score 80):

Make sure that "Enable 32 - Bit Applications" is set to false for the app pool.

Comment: This works if you want to use the x86 dll on 64 bit machine. In our case, our dev and production environments don't match so this was what worked best.

Comment: Setting it to true for me actually solved the issue. I guess Elmah ships with the 32bit sql lite assembly by default.

Comment: +1 for both @Jirapong and Sergey because it was this setting I had to manipulate to get things working. In my case I think I had the x86 version of the SqlLite DLL and needed Enable 32 - Bit Applications to be set to "true."

Answer (score 45):

Go to the `IIS7 Application Pool -> advanced settings and set the 32-bit application to true`.

Comment: I'm running windows 7, and I hit this issue; turning 32-bit on fixed it for me, presumably because my copy of the DLL was 32-bit.

Comment: FYI : It was required to set the application pool identity to LocalSystem to get this working :^

Comment: And make sure to have a Win32 version of the SQLite.Interop.dll
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816529/corflags-exe-system-data-sqlite-dll-and-badimageformatexception/4839285

Answer (score 15):

This is very simple if you are not using SQLite:

You can delete the SQLite DLLs from your solution's bin folders, then from the folder where you reference ELMAH. Rebuild, and your app won't try to load this DLL that you are not using.

Comment: +1 If you are not using SQLite, then why bother fixing up the referenced DLL? Nice, elegant and just what I needed.

Comment: This worked locally but I then got the error after deploying to Azure.

Comment: In my case, upon deletion, it appears again.

Answer (score 9):

I have a 64 bit dev machine and 32 bit build server.  I used this code prior to NHibernate initialisation.  Works a charm on any architecture (well the 2 I have tested)

Hope this helps someone.

Guido

```
        private static void LoadSQLLiteAssembly()
        {
            Uri dir = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dir.AbsolutePath);           
            string binFile = fi.Directory.FullName + "\\System.Data.SQLite.DLL";
            if (!File.Exists(binFile)) File.Copy(GetAppropriateSQLLiteAssembly(), binFile, false);
        }

        private static string GetAppropriateSQLLiteAssembly()
        {
            string pa = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
            string arch = ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(pa) || String.Compare(pa, 0, "x86", 0, 3, true) == 0) ? "32" : "64");
            return GetLibsDir() + "\\NUnit\\System.Data.SQLite.x" + arch + ".DLL";
        }
```

Comment: Has anyone successfully used this technique? I tried it in a test asp.net mvc app solution and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Instead of going to environment variable, you can use the CLR directly:
string arch = IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "x64" : "x86";

Comment: Or the [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) property (since .NET4).

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this by installing System.Data.SQLite with Nuget extension. This extension can use for Visual Studio 2010 or higher.
First, you have to install Nuget extension. You can follow here:

- Go to Visual Studio 2010, Menu --> Tools
- Select Extension Manager
- Enter NuGet in the search box and click Online Gallery. Waiting it Retrieve information…
- Select the retrieved NuGet Package Manager, click Download. Waiting it Download…
- Click Install on the Visual Studio Extension Installer NuGet Package Manager. Wait for the installation to complete.
- Click Close and 'Restart Now.

Second, now, you can install SQLite:

- Go to the menu TOOLS->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Console of the Visual studio.
- Then run the command Install-Package System.Data.SQLite in Package Manager Console. Like this:
  [run the command Install-Package System.Data.SQLite in Package Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl8TG.jpg)

And now, you can use System.Data.SQLite.

In the case, you see two folder x64 and, x86, these folders contain SQLite.Interop.dll. Now go to the properties windows of those dlls and set build action is content and Copy to output directory is Copy always.

So, that is my way.

Thanks.
Kim Tho Pham,
HoChiMinh City, Vietnam.
Email: tho.phamkim@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

In our case didn't work because our production server has missing

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

We installed it and all work fine. The Application Pool must have Enable 32-bit Applications set to true and you must the x86 version of the library

Comment: Works for me. It just gives an error message without pointing out the C library is missing, which is awful.

Comment: For me I have installed vcredist 2008 x64 for System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139

Answer (score 5):

As someone who's had to deal with quite a few bug reports on Roadkill Wiki with exactly the same issue, this is what you need to do:

- Are you using x64 or x86? Sqlite comes with DLLs for separate architectures - copy the right one to your bin folder, there are two DLLS for the official provider: `System.Data.SQLite.dll` `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`
- If you can't be bothered hunting around for these assemblies, enable 32 bit mode for your App Pool (a solution for dev machines only usually)
- If you're hosting on a server, you'll need the Microsoft C++ Runtime redistributable - it's not installed on Server 2008 R2 by default. [x64 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523), [x86 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

It's a real pain in the ass how many hoops you have to jump through when re-distributing the SQLite .NET binaries, my solution for Roadkill in the end was to copy the correct binaries to the ~/bin folder based on the architecture your using. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the C++ runtime issue.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when our windows server was converted from 32 bit OS to 64 bit.  The assembly that was throwing the error was set to compile in x86 mode (ie 32 mode).  I switched it to "Any CPU" and that did the trick.  You can change this value by doing the following:

right click on the project go to `Properties -> Build -> Platform Target -> change to "Any CPU"`

Comment: I was trying to use 32 bit System.Data.SQLite.dll and getting this exception when running on 64 bit cpu.  I changed the platform target from "Any CPU" to "x86" and it made the exception go away.  I figure unless you are looking to maximize performance it is better to build for the least common denominator so that it should run on either a 32 or 64 bit cpu.

Answer (score 4):

Manual load related System.Data.SQLite assembly can resolve this.

Changed gatapia's Code as below:

```
    public static void LoadSQLLiteAssembly()
    {
        Uri dir = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dir.AbsolutePath);
        string appropriateFile = Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, GetAppropriateSQLLiteAssembly());
        Assembly.LoadFrom(appropriateFile);
    }

    private static string GetAppropriateSQLLiteAssembly()
    {
        string pa = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
        string arch = ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(pa) || String.Compare(pa, 0, "x86", 0, 3, true) == 0) ? "32" : "64");
        return "System.Data.SQLite.x" + arch + ".DLL";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this, oddly enough, by installing System.Data.SQLite via the Nuget GUI application, as opposed to the package manager console.

Installing via the console didn't include the dependencies this library needs to run.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Data.SQLite` has a dependency on `System.Data.SQLite.interop` make sure both packages are the same version and are both **x86**.

This is an old question, but I tried all the above. I was working on a strictly **x86** project, so there was not two folders /x86, /x64. But for some reason, the `System.Data.SQLite` was a different version to `System.Data.SQLite.interop`, once I pulled down matching dlls the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with 2 quick solutions. Either work for me. I think the problem is because of permissions.

1) Instead of using the Elmah.dll file from the net-2.0 directory, I used Elmah.dll from net-1.1 .

2) Instead of keeping Elmah.dll in the project bin directory. I make a dll directory to put it in.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around this is just to upgrade your application to ELMAH 1.2 rather than 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2022, I set the Bitness to x86 instead of Default while using IIS Express. That fixed the issue without having to change any binaries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete your bin debug folder and recompile again?

Or check your project reference to the `System.Data.SQLite`, track down where it is located, then open the dll in reflector. If you can't open it, that means that the dll is corrupted, you might want to find a correct one or reinstall the .net framework.

Comment: I've tried adding the reference to System.Data.SQLite directly (aside from removing bin and obj) and I've got this error: Error 1 Warning as Error: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' targets a different processor MyProject

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS Express as the web server on your development machine I would change to Local IIS.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but it may help some people searching on this error to try setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True for the app pool. That is what resolved the error for me. I came upon this solution by reading some the comments to @beckelmw's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have the wrong package installed. You want the package produced by [Microsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/) which implements the System.Data.Common provider model.

Answer (score 0):

As all solutions didn't work for me, I tried this:
I deleted this folder C:\Users....nuget\packages\stub.system.data.sqlite.core.netframework
Then I installed System.Data.SQLite.Core from Nuget Package Manager
And "wow!!!!" it works,