# SQLLite.dll is not seen by few PC's

Tags: sqlite, dll

I have a C# app what have dll of SQLLite. I have added this like a reference and set Copy Local to true. 
I use this dll as normal: `using System.Data.SQLite;`

I place an exe, my dll's in exe's directory and some people have problem with seeing this dll and some not. 
I got exceptions `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified`

I cannot manage, why on most of PC works fine, but doesnt on other.

Any clues, what to check?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. Same on every PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'System.Data.SQLite.dll*" requires "*msvcr100.dll*" which is one of it's Dependencies. This will be available only if you installed latest "*Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable*" or any other product which internally provides this.

For example, VS2010 will install C++ Redistributable by default. Thats the reason your application doesnot works in some machine but works in others.

You could try pasting the "msvcr100.dll" in your application bin folder and distribute if you dont want to install C++ Redist in all the PC's.

If the above solution doesnot helps, then take a look at the below similar post.

> >
>   [On some computers application can't load sqlite dll file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621758/on-some-computers-application-cant-load-sqlite-dll-file?rq=1)