# Using Elmah with Cassini

Tags: asp.net, iis, elmah, cassini

Does anyone know if I can use Elmah with Visual Studio build-in web server(aka Cassini)? 
I get it working easily on IIS, but using same configuration, it doesn't work with Cassini. When I requested the log page via http://localhost:62364/elmah.axd, I had "The resource cannot be found."

Answer (score 1):

I can't give any insight to what's causing your issue, but I can say that it works fine for me both in Cassini running on localhost and deployed to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an x64 version of ELMAH you will run into configuration problems, as outlined here: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)