# IIS 7.5 refuses to load 64-bit assembly - possible CAS problem?

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, orchardcms, system.data.sqlite, code-access-security

I just downloaded the [Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com/), opened it up in VS2008 and hit F5: Everything runs fine.

I then created a website in IIS 7.5 and pointed it to the web project's directory and set up permissions correctly (I hope). I downloaded the 64-bit version System.Data.SQLite as suggested here: [Orchard Work Item 14798](http://orchard.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=14798) and here: [SO: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite).

The site runs in Full Trust. When I point my browser to the site running through IIS I get

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or
>   one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests.

I don't know much about Code Access Security (if that is even what's at play here), so I am at a loss here. What am I doing wrong / not understanding / not seeing? How do I provide appropriate permissions and to whom / what?

Is there any hope of ever deploying this application to a hoster where I am only allowed to run in Medium Trust?

Any help, pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

NOTE: the question is not why this initially worked when run through Cassini. The answer to that question is contained in the answer to the SO question referenced above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQLite provider uses P/Invoke to communicate with the underlying engine and therefore cannot run in medium trust. This makes SQLite inappropriate for the majority of hosting providers.