# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0

Tags: c#, sqlite

Although there's an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite) the circumstances are different however. For instance, in one application System.Data.SQLite works perfectly while in this one keeps on throwing this exception on the following line:

```
 SQLiteSync.SqliteClientSyncProvider clientSyncProvider = new SQLiteSync.SqliteClientSyncProvider(connString);
```

and I did check the path too, to avoid I/O exceptions.
Any clues on might throw this ?

Comment: Did you check that the dll is really there?

Comment: twice. and also removed it and added it again just to be sure.

Comment: Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common reason I know for this is that SQLite comes in x86 version only and people run it up on x64 bit machines and it doesn't like it.

You can solve this problem (if that's what you have) by changing your build settings from "Any CPU" to "x86". This would explain why it works in one application and not another - if one was running in x86 fine and one was running in x64 and causing this error.

Comment: The issue persists even though I did change the settings as you suggested. What strikes me as is that Sqlite works perfectly in another project with the same settings(without even setting the CPU to x86), but not in this case. 
my guess is that it has something to do with sqlitesync...

Comment: As a side not.  I have found that this issue can also happen if the Visual C++ re-distributable is not installed on Windows XP.