# CorFlags.exe, System.Data.SQLite.dll and BadImageFormatException

Tags: .net, sqlite, 64-bit, clr, badimageformatexception

Running [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80,printer%29.aspx) against `System.Data.SQLite.dll` from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ produces the following output.

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 24
ILONLY    : 0
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 1
```

As you can see, `32BIT` is not specified and `PE` is equal to `PE32`. According to *[Moving from 32-bit to 64-bit application development on .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravseth/archive/2006/03/07/545104.aspx)*, this means that the assembly is *Any CPU*. However, using the assembly from a 64 bit application results in an error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect
>   format. File name:
>   'System.Data.SQLite'

If CorFlags.exe is reporting *Any CPU*, why does the exception occur? Is the assembly incorrectly marked with `32BIT: 0`?

I know that there is a 64-bit version available too, I'm just want to know what is causing the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The System.Data.SQLite.dll file you are using is a [mixed-mode assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx), which means it is not a pure .NET code (see also the “ILONLY : 0” flag), it contains also unmanaged machine code, which cannot be “Any CPU”. So, as the DLL contains 32-bit native code, it can be loaded only into 32-bit process, otherwise a BadImageFormatException occurs.

Comment: @Mormegil - I understand why the exception is thrown. I just want to know why it does not have the 32BIT flag marked.

Comment: @Giorgi Well… because nobody set the flag. The point is that the ILONLY flag is not set. In that case, the assembly contains non-managed code, for which the 32BIT flag is not relevant, and if the DLL is not a PE+, it is considered to be 32-bit only (if it were a PE+, it would be 64-bit only). Only with ILONLY flag set does the 32BIT determine whether the DLL should be considered 32-bit only, or AnyCPU.

Comment: @Mormegil - so you mean that if the assembly is 64bit the 32BIT flag should be ignored?

Comment: @Giorgi - AFAIK, the “algorithm” is: If the DLL is in the PE+ format (i.e. native, machine set to x64), it is 64bit, otherwise, check the ILONLY flag: If not set, it is 32bit. Otherwise, check the 32BIT flag: if set, it is 32bit, if not set, it is AnyCPU.

Comment: @Giorgi - I don’t think the whole thing is spelled out in a single “official” document. You can deduce parts of it from the CLI specification (II.24, II.25) and the PE specification. I don’t know where (if?) do mixed-mode assemblies have their specification.

Comment: @Mormegil you save my life.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the `SQLite-1.0.66.0-binaries.zip` file from sourceforget.net then this contains a **bin/x64** directory with a `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file which is what you are looking for.

It also has an Itanium directory too..

The [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/

Comment: as I have said in my answer I am aware of the 64bit version. I am interested why the 32bit one does not have the flag.

Comment: The one in bin/Managed is 100% managed and requires an appropriate sqlite3.dll, so if you use this and grab a x86 version of sqlite3.dll from www.sqlite.org it should do what you want.