# SQLite and MSDEV 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I am writing an application which requires a database.  I am using SQLite and it seemed to be going well but one day I got the error:

> System.BadImageFormatException
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load >a program with an incorrect format.

I am not sure what I have done to cause this.  I searched for this issue and found solutions in previous questions.  I have added the lines:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">    
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>  
 </startup>
```

in my .config file, although the full text is:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">    
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>    
     <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506"/>  
 </startup>
```

Does the different required runtime affect this?

The other solution was to set copy local to true on the SQLite assembly but this did not help.

Can anyone offer any more advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [corflags, System.Data.SQLite.dll and BadImageFormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816529/corflags-system-data-sqlite-dll-and-badimageformatexception)

Comment: This question is tagged C++, but I see only .NET.

Comment: Question does not seem to be a duplicate.  The other asks about why the 32bit flag has not been set rather than how to fix this error.  Good spot on the C++ tag, sorry it was force of habbit!!!

Answer (score 0):

The exception System.BadImageFormatException is very frequently connected to 32bit 64bit mishaps.
Perhaps you are targeting a 32bit application and referencing the 64bit verision of SQLite or the opposite. Look at your references and at your build configuration

Comment: Pretty sure you're right, this is a very common question around here.

Comment: I have set the build configuration to target 64bit and the path of SQLite is: C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLite.NET\bin\x64\System.Data.SQLite.DLL which I took to mean was the 64 bit version.  Have I misunderstood?