# Could not load assembly System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: sqlite, exception, load, assemblies

I have a perfectly working windows forms C# .NET 4 application that uses a SQLite3 database file to store data and display forms.

When I deploy my app on any machine other then the dev machine, I get an exception thrown and it's message is "Could not load assembly System.Data.SQLite.dll or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

The System.Data.SQLite.dll reference in the project is set to Copy Local = True. Also, I tried manually loading the assembly with Assembly.LoadFile. The dll is placed in the output directory. I also tried setting the platform target to Any CPU as well as x86, no difference. All machines I am working with are 32-bit. What is the issue here? Why is my application trying to load the assembly and can't find it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at SO Thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite

Comment: thanks, but this looks like a solution for a web application. Mine is a windows forms application and the solution you attached didn't work..

Comment: How do you deploy? Do you have a setup project, copy the release folder?

Comment: I just copy the debug folder for testing

Comment: if you have not tried, just remove the reference and add it freshly once again. several times that saved my ass

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem after publishing my program to a separate computer. Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (**x86**) on the separate computer fixed the problem.

Note: the separate computer already had Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (**x64**) installed, the **x86** version was needed.

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know, I was just trying to give credit to where I had originally found the answer to problem. I imagine my explanation will be enough if the cause of the problem is the same.

Answer (score 8):

'System.Data.SQLite.dll" requires "msvcr100.dll" which is one of it's Dependencies. This will be available only if you installed latest "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable" or any other product which internally provides this.

For example, VS2010 will install C++ Redistributable by default. Thats the reason your application doesnot works in some machine but works in others.

You could try pasting the "msvcr100.dll" in your application bin folder and distribute if you dont want to install VC++ 2010 Redist in all the PC's.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the System.Data.Sqlite.dll modules depend on the  *"Microsoft Visual C++   **2012** Redistributable Package"* .

You can find required dependencies on the official download page : http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given didn't solve my problem. I tried to deploy to a VMware server. The solution that did help where given here: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/System-Data-SQLite-Deployment-Mystery-td71752.html Two methods are described there.

1. When i install this sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.88.0.exe, my app is able to find the right dll.
2. The second method is to add the dll to de app.exe.config in the debug or release dir. If you edit this file directly, there is a change VC will overwrite the file.

My main problem was that i installed the sqlite package manually. I didn't use NuGet, because i'm behind a proxy. If you do use Nuget, the information in the app.exe.config will be provided automatically.

Using NuGet behind a proxy is described here: [NuGet Behind Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy#)