# NuGet behind a proxy

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I figure out that NuGet allows proxy settings configuration since [1.4 version (June 2011)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-1.4). But, I can't find any command line example.

I'm trying to run some build and NuGet can't connect.

How do I configure the proxy settings on the command line?

Comment: For the benefit of other users encountering proxy issues: You'll know it could be the proxy if NuGet displays the message: "The remote name could not be resolved: 'nuget.org'"

Comment: Be careful to check the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables as well as your system proxy settings

Comment: There's an issue for it now on github:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/458

Answer (score 254):

Here's what I did to get this working with my corporate proxy that uses NTLM authentication. I downloaded **[NuGet.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)** and then ran the following commands (which I found in the comments to [this discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20130207063850/http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1924) on CodePlex):

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://my.proxy.address:port
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=mydomain\myUserName
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=mySuperSecretPassword
```

This put the following in my `NuGet.config` located at `%appdata%\NuGet` (which maps to *C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming* on my Windows 7 machine):

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://my.proxy.address:port" />
        <add key="http_proxy.user" value="mydomain\myUserName" />
        <add key="http_proxy.password" value="base64encodedHopefullyEncryptedPassword" />
    </config>
    <!-- stuff -->
</configuration>
```

Incidentally, this also fixed my issue with NuGet only working the first time I hit the package source in Visual Studio.

> *Note that some people who have tried this approach have reported through the comments that they have been able to omit setting the `http_proxy.password` key from the command line, or delete it after-the-fact from the config file, and were still able to have NuGet function across the proxy.*

If you find, however, that you *must* specify your password in the NuGet config file, **remember that you have to update the stored password in the NuGet config from the command line when you change your network login, if your proxy credentials are also your network credentials**.

Comment: The NuGet command-line did not add the entries to my NuGet.config file, but once I manually edited the file, it worked great.

Comment: In my case, I omitted the **http_proxy.password** key completely and it seemed to be happy to pass through my authenticated AD credentials.  This saves the need to change the password frequently.

Comment: **Warning** Be careful when you use the configuration suggested by arcain. Make sure you change the password in the config file when you change your Windows password. My Windows account was randomly locked out after changing the password as per the company policy. It took me few hours to figure out that its this config entry causing this whole trouble. The best option is to simply remove the **http_proxy.password** key as suggested by @Sir Crispalot

Comment: Try what Sir Crispalot mentioned and remove the http_proxy.password key.  That has worked for some people and allowed them to avoid having to change the password in the NuGet config file.

Comment: Another victory here -- using these settings and omitting the password key worked for me behind my corporate proxy with NTLM authentication.

Comment: It worked for me without password as mentioned in the answer. Thanks arcain!

Comment: @CharlesBurns Link updated.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I only ran the first two commands to set the proxy server and user name, and it worked. No password necessary in my case.

Comment: Not working. I followed the above instructions to setup the Nuget.config since I was behind a company firewall and was facing the proxy issue. But now after adding the proxy in the NugetPackageManager -> PackageSources : nuget.org is getting automatically unchecked. So, I went to the Nuget.config file getting generated in the  %appdata%\NuGet, there looks to be this tag <disabledPackageSources> getting generated which has the 'nuget.org'. If I delete the proxy config it won't get generated. Facing a weird issue. Need help

Comment: it works without username and password and you need to restart VS if it was open :)

Comment: @arcain None, of these works for me, tried all of them. On CentOs

Answer (score 28):

Maybe you could try this to your **devenv.exe.config**

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxyaddress" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

I found it from the [NuGet Issue tracker](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/231)

There are also other valuable comments about NuGet + network issues.

Comment: but this assumes the devenve.exe (Visual Studio that is) is installed, which should not be in a build server

Comment: I had to remove this setting to make it work, so that it follows IE's proxy settings.

Comment: `xml
<system.net>
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
      </defaultProxy>
      <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
      </settings>
    </system.net>
`

Work for me, it used the system proxy settings. Tested on WINDOWS 10

Answer (score 15):

Just in case you are using the HTTPS version of [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org), be aware that you have to set the values with HTTPS.

- `https_proxy`
- `https_proxy.user`
- `https_proxy.password`

Comment: The https password is plain text in nuget.config if you follow arcains guide but using https

Comment: This fixed my issue, more details here https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5980.

Comment: So we cannot use 'http' to set proxy address if we are using the https version of nuget?

Answer (score 8):

I could be wrong but I thought it used IE's proxy settings.

If it sees that you need to login it opens a dialog and asks you to do so (login that is).

Please see the description of this here -> http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.5

Comment: It does - the issue with this approach arises when your corporation's group policy continually reverts your IE settings to ones that do not work with Nuget, as happens at my place of work

Answer (score 7):

Another flavor for same "proxy for nuget": alternatively you can set your nuget proxing settings to connect through [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Below cmd will save proxy settings in in default nuget config file for user at `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`

```
nuget config -Set HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

Whenever you need nuget to reach out the internet, just open Fiddler, asumming you have fiddler listening on default port 8888.

This configuration is not sensitive to passwork changes because fiddler will resolve any authentication with up stream proxy for you.

Answer (score 7):

The solution for me was to include

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://<IP>:<Port>" />
    <add key="http_proxy.user" value="<user>" />
    <add key="http_proxy.password" value="<password>" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

In the `nuget.config` file.

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: @MarceloMachado: Here: %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config

Comment: user's nuget.config location on Windows 10 : %AppData%\Roaming\Nuget\NuGet.config

Comment: You can choose to do ` <add key="http_proxy" value="http://<IP>:<Port>" />` alone without specifying username and password. Remember to restart Visual Studio after that!

Comment: Restarting VS is important! Also, I think I had issues running as Admin (needed to run as a regular user?)

Comment: Two other helpful items: you can add "https_proxy" and "no_proxy" values, too.  Also, the default NuGet config I found was at "%APPDATA%\NuGet", but you can define nuget.config files in a solution's directory that overrides that default file.

Answer (score 5):

To anyone using VS2015: I was encountering a "407 Proxy Authentication required" error, which broke my build. After a few hours investigating, it turns out MSBuild wasn't sending credentials when trying to download Nuget as part of the 'DownloadNuGet' target. The solution was to add the following XML to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config inside the `<configuration>` element:

```
<system.net>
            <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
            </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps someone else. For me the solution was to open NuGet settings on Visual Studio (2015/2017) and add a new feed URL: http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.

I didn't have to change any proxy related settings.

Comment: This was the winner for me. Strangely, on my cube PC the original feed URL works but on a lab PC (on a more "secure" network) it failed

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Server 2016 Standard, which is what I develop on, I just had to open the Credential Manager Control Panel and clear out the cached proxy settings for Visual Studio which were no longer valid and then restart Visual Studio. The next time I opened the Nuget Package Manager I was prompted for proxy credentials, which got me working again.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager

Comment: Worked for me when getting 407 errors for an internal corporate repo.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition...

If it works for you to only supply the http_proxy setting and not username and password I'd recommend putting the proxy settings in a project local nuget.config file and commit it to source control. That way all team members get the same settings.

Create an empty .\nuget.config

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
   </configuration>
```

Then:

```
   nuget config -Set http_proxy="http://myproxy.example.com:8080" -ConfigFile .\Nuget.Config
```

And finally commit your new project local Nuget.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Hello for me going into

%appdata%/Roaming/Nuget/NuGet.Config and removing every line except for the package sources. Which should give something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Full path should be C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Basically there was a proxy set, i don't how and why it was set but it was there and i couldn't ping it either.

Answer (score 1):

It's correlated, but not the same cenario here, but I would like to document for those on Linux.

I'm on Fedora 35 using VsCode and dotnet sdk 6 installed

To use `dotnet add package` behind proxy I have to use this format of command:

`export http_proxy=http://[user]:[pass]@[server]:[port] && dotnet add package <package>`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747011/104344). Basically, connection could fail if your system doesn't trust nuget certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the suggestions from @arcain I had to add the following Windows Azure Content Delivery Network url to our proxy server's the white-list:

```
.msecnd.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Solution by @arcain  Plus below steps solved me the issue

1. Modifying the "package sources" under Nuget package manger settings to check 
   the checkbox to use the nuget.org settings resolved my issue.
2. I did also changed to use that(nuget.org) as the first choice of package source
   I did uncheck my company package sources to ensure the nuget was always picked 
   up from global sources.

Answer (score 0):

As a late answer, for me nothing worked here. I guess this might depend on your company proxies or how the `nuget` is implemented but for some reason I had the following environment variables set: `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. After I removed them, `nuget` started working correctly.