# Adding Packages to build so nuget doesn't need to retrieve each build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, tfs

I will explain this as best I can!!

I have a large project with a build that kicks off automatically after each checkin. This normally works fine, but this is the first time I have attempted a build that has included code using a library other than those already in the solution.

I have added the Microsoft antixss library (I got it through nuget on my local dev machine). When I checkin, the build fails as nuget on the build server is having trouble getting out to nuget through our proxy.

Obviously the best solution is to get this issue resolved, but it brings up a question of resilience - if our connection to the outside world is mashed, can I not do any builds?

This led me to thinking, is it possible to add libraries such as this antixss to the defaults that always appear in my build servers packages (like jquery etc?). Each build, this packages folder is cleared and replaced by the build process. At the moment, every-time I build the build breaks due to the proxy issue.

I really need to get a release out today, so was wondering if anyone could help me here? It seems silly that I need to go out to Nuget as the library exists on my local!!

Many Many thanks

Comment: why you having proxy issues? did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy

Comment: Hope this link also explain more about your problem http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx

Comment: We are having issues authenticating - it is an internal policy issue rather than a problem with the technology..

Comment: if Internal security policy is the issue , I think you need to set up your own nu-get feed and add the packages. you can even use a shared network location. Read the step 0 in this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetForTheEnterpriseNuGetInAContinuousIntegrationAutomatedBuildSystem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install your own nuget server behind the firewall/proxy and point to that as your default NuGet server.

I've used the free version of [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/overview) in the past as an easy to run a nuget server that also acts as a caching proxy for the main nuget gallery. It also means that if the main nuget server or your internet connection is down you will still have a nuget server that your build can connect to.