# MSBuild fails on Unit Test Project (.NET Core) after NuGet Restore

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

## ISSUE

The Visual Studio Build task in a Visual Studio Team Services build for a solution that contains a default ASP.NET MVC website and a default Unit Test Project is failing to find references. This task runs after a NuGet Restore that should install these references, but even though the NuGet Restore task succeeds, the references are not installed on the server running this build.

## Visual Studio Team Services Logs

The error logs have been uploaded to [This Github Repository](https://github.com/Fredison/MSBuildError)

## Attempted Fixes

In an effort to ensure that the packages are properly referenced by the project, all of the NuGet packages were reinstalled from Package Manager using the following command:

```
PM> Update-Package --reinstall
```

This only caused MSBuild to not find `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` in both the projects. So in an attempt to correct this, the version of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` in the project was dropped to version `2.3.2`. However, this only brought back the original errors where the `MSTest.TestAdapter.props` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` references could not be found.

Comment: Can you post the contento of your SampleWebSiteForDemo.csproj file...or you can add it to the repo

Comment: @Hackerman sample website files have been added to the [repository](https://github.com/Fredison/MSBuildError/tree/master/SampleWebsite)

Comment: Delete this line `<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />` then install the package again...and also delete the `<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with these tasks (works fine for me with the sample solution you shared):

1. NuGet Tool Installer (Version of NuGet.exe to install: 4.3.0)
2. NuGet restore (Choose 2.* version)
3. Visual Studio Build (Visual Studio Version: Latest)
4. Queue build with the agent that has VS2017 installed.

Comment: I am getting an `ERR:connect ETIMEDOUT 72.21.81.200:443` that is causing the NuGet Tool Installer task to fail, my theory is that this is due to the fact that I am operating behind a proxy. I have supplied proxy authentication to the agent, but does this task also require it's own credentials? If so, how do I provide them?

Comment: Try to specify proxy in config file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy#answer-15463892