# asp.net core 2.0 not building in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, tfs-2015, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to CI and TFS 2015.

I have created a .net core 2.0 webapi and trying to setup the CI using TFS 2015.

I am getting the error as shown in the attachment. Also i have attached the setup i did in TFS 2015 to build asp.net core application.

Can anyone please help to solve this?
[image: Setup]
[image: error]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like NuGet restore is fighting your proxy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15463892/736079

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet Behind Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log has indicated a 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) error. Try the steps below:

- download the command line version of nuget
- add it to the path env var
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://proxy:port
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=Domain\Username
- nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=myPassword

Comment: Thank you. Do i need to do this on the physical server? I am bascially accessing via browser right now. Sorry if it is silly question :)

Comment: You need to do this on your build agent machine.

Comment: Thank you. It is really helpful

Comment: Sorry. It really help me. Thanks