# "The remote name could not be resolved: 'nuget.org'"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

We are trying to setup CI in Visual studio environment using TFS.

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017
- MSVSTFS V 16.12
- NuGet V 4.0

**Getting below error:**

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: 
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
```

Went through many links shared in the community by the developers which were of truly great help to understand the issue.

**Some of my workarounds:**

1. http://skolima.blogspot.ru/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html

   - This explained about NuGet.config settings to be done
2. [NuGet Behind Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy/15463892#15463892)

   - Very resourceful stackoverflow chain,  I followed the steps of creating a NuGet.config like exactly mentioned here and my config file looked of the form:

[image: NuGet.config which I created]

I am behind a company's firewall and we are trying to setup CI/CD pipeline.

In TFS:
[image: TFS Build NuGet Error]

I am sure this a firewall proxy setting issue. Since I am able to access `"api.nuget.org"` out of the network.

Can someone suggest what is missing in `NuGet.config` to which i am pointing? Any other inputs free to share.

Comment: Did you mean you work properly by using the workaround in locally visual studio, but still get error info in TFS build?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT even in local it does not seem to pick the change. NuGet.config 'http' proxy I have added does not seem to be getting used.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, then why you say it's a workaround? How would the workaround infect your build result? Or did you just mean what you have tried for those "workarounds"?

Comment: I am trying those workarounds to resolve the nuget.org firewall issue but to no result.

Comment: What's the result if you run nuget restore command on the build agent machine manually?

Comment: @abhi11  Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use Nuget behind Proxy, you should follow  the steps in `Nuget.config`

Since you have post the workaround above, however still get the error info in TFS.

You should make sure you also changed the `Nuget.config` in your build agent/server. Win+R and enter 
`%appdata%\nuget` to get the file location.

Try to build directly through visual studio on the server instead of through TFS. This will narrow down if the issue is related to your environment or TFS side.

Moreover, you could also  Verbose Output to get more detail log info for troubleshooting: [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/)