# Dotnet Core Nuget set proxy

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm running dotnet core 2.2, and I would like set a proxy as I receive this when running dotnet restore:

`NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [C:\Projects\FarrisCosting\Projects.csproj]`

Per another post, these commands are possible:

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://my.proxy.address:port
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=mydomain\myUserName
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=mySuperSecretPassword
```

Using the dotnet core conventions I would expect to have the following available: 
 `dotnet nuget config -set`, but this does not appear to be available.

I'm wondering if I may need to run nuget directly from the SDK without encapsulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing nuget from this post and running the appropriate commands supported the workaround.

[NuGet Behind Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy)

Would still like to see those commands integrated into dotnet coret.