# Installation of pythonnet on Ubuntu 18.04 - problems with nuget.exe

Tags: linux, mono, nuget, python.net

I try to install the `pythonnet` library on linux, but I can have trouble with nuget/mono.

I tryed to run the following ([Install pythonnet on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.7 64-bit, Mono 5.16 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058757/install-pythonnet-on-ubuntu-18-04-python-3-6-7-64-bit-mono-5-16-fails)):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install clang
sudo apt install nuget
git config --global http.proxy http://my.proxy.address:port
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pycparser --user
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pythonnet --user
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

When I clone the repository from github and just run `mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self`, I get the following error:

`Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/. Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.`

I came across this link: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880, but most of the advice is Windows focussed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and needed to install mono first:

> sudo apt-get install mono-complete

Comment: yes i solved it. Addionally what got me in trouble was that the image is built with Debian 9, while my system is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: In my case, `clang` is also required. And nuget for System.TupleValue package.