# Error caused when trying to Installing package in .Net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, install.packages

When I tried to install the Package in Visual Studio 2017 using below command,

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel -Version 7.0.0
```

I got the following error

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.7.0.0' with respect to project 'Portal.System', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
>
> Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.7.0.0' from source 'nuget.org'.
>
> error occurred while sending the request.
>   The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org' At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel -Version 7.0.0
> - ```
>    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException, NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   ```

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: VS menu Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates and check if there is no updates for NuGet Package Manager. Install the latest version,

Comment: The error says "The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'". This means your internet isn't working correctly.

Comment: @NivasPandian Starting from Visual Studio 2017, NuGet is no longer an extension in the Visual Studio Marketplace, and is bundled with Visual Studio through the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with **zivkan**, this issue could be related to Internet connection when you're using VS2017.

Especially you need to check if you can access `nuget.org` website by your IE browser. I think this issue indicates something is wrong with your `DNS provider`. Please check this point and fix the connections.

In addition: If you're using nuget.org behind proxy, some details about the [nuget.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-a-proxy/15463892#15463892) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest nuget commandline util from [https://www.nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
then run below command

```
nuget.exe locals -clear all
```

Restart your visual studio.
this problem to occur on any system with a fresh installation of Windows/VS/tooling so likely a bug with their installers.