# Unable to download any Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

This issue has been there for a while now. My internet connection is very good. However, I am unable to download any VS marketplace extension. I am able to get all extension lists from VS, but always unable to download it from Extensions -> Manage Extensions or even from VS marketplace website

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to get all extension lists from VS, but always unable to
>   download it from Extensions -> Manage Extensions or even from VS
>   marketplace website.

When you click the **Update** button in VS `Extensions Manager UI`, it actually downloads the xx.vsix from [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) website. So I think the root cause is that you can't download the extension from the website, and it could be something wrong with `Internet Connection`. You can try to access the marketplace website with **IE browser** to check this point.

I assume this issue is similar to [Error caused when trying to Installing package in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57566115/10910450), it might be something wrong with your DNS or proxy, or maybe the settings in your firewall corrupt the download. I think that's why your Internet is good but can't access the website well.

And if you can't resolve the Internet issue in short time, I suggest you can try to install the extension you need by another machine which can access the website successfully. An extension is a xx.vsix package, you can install it from the website by another machine and copy the xx.vsix to your current machine, double-click it to install or update automatically. (And if it works, it actually indicates something is wrong with your Internet.)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.