# Extensions not downloading/updating

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.5 and trying to download any extension and it doesn't work so I tried to update existing extension and all my try end up with the same error this error :

[image]

so I thought that windows firewall could effected visual studio so I turn it off and still can't update or download any Extention 
I also tried to close my solution and download extension but it also doesn't work, I tried to search for solution on the internet but I didn't find something useful 
now I have no idea what to do to fix this problem.

Comment: Open a command-line and ping that address. If it doesn't ping, your issue is DNS related.

Comment: I tried it but my network is fine

Comment: Hi Kero, any update for this issue? Maybe you can try using another machine to download the extension manually from the website, and copy the xx.vsix to your current machine to install it. This issue could be related to something wrong in your DNS, proxy, firewall or what, so manually downloading the extension using another machine can be a temporary workaround for you.

Comment: i waiting to travel so I can use another DNS maybe I got problem with my current dns I tried to stop firewall and it doesn't work and tried to download xx.vsix manually the website always crash when I try to download

Comment: @KeroFawzy Sorry for the delay, I didn't get the notification from SO :( Have you checked if it makes a difference when you use different browser. (IE, edge, google...) Same result?

Comment: yeah they all give me same result

Comment: See [Fixing DNS errors](https://support.bintube.com/hc/en-us/articles/231563987-Fixing-DNS-Errors-Remote-name-could-not-be-resolved#targetText=%22Remote%20name%20could%20not%20be,to%20use%20different%20DNS%20servers.),

Answer (score 1):

***(Without enough info to reproduce, I can't give a direct answer.Here are some troubleshootings and to avoid losing contact in round-trip comments, I post it as answer instead of comments)***

Check if you can access the [Cloud Explorer for VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.CloudExplorerForVS2019) using **IE** browser, and then you can try to download the `xx.vsix or xx.zip` there.

If the `remote name not resolved` error only occurs when downloading extensions in VS, I agree that this issue is related to VS. But if we failed to download the extension from the website with **IE**, I think we can locate this issue is related to Internet connection issues.(Because VS actually fetch the vsix package from the marketplace just like we did manually by browser. See this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861943/unable-to-download-any-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-extension). I have no idea what kind of Internet issue could result in it, but since VS use same Internet settings like IE browser, if we can't download that extension in **IE**, then we can't do it in VS either.

`Go Tools=>Options=>Environment=>Web Browser` you can find `Internet Explorer options` there with the **note**:

> except for home-page settings, all changes made to IE will affect
>   **both IE and Internal browser in VS**.

So if you can't access the website and download the extension manually from VS marketplace by **IE**, this issue could be related to your Internet options,Corporate Firewall...

But if you can download the extension manually from VS marketplace, firstly you can double-click the xx.vsix to manually install or update the extension to VS.(If it's a xx.zip file, rename it to xx.vsix)  And then run a [VS repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and clean all [VS cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md)(VS2019--16.*) to check if it helps to resolve the issue in VS.