# "dotnet" command does nothing

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to install a global package through `dotnet cli` but the command `dotnet` does nothing. I don't get an error message that says the command is not found etc. but it also doesn't run.

[image]

Between each line, cursor inside the powershell (or command prompt) turns into `Working In Background` ( [image] ) mode but after just a few seconds, it just gets into the new line without doing anything. During these few seconds, if I move the cursor outside the prompt, it goes back to regular mode. So it's doing something I guess.

What is happening here, and how can I solve this issue?

---

**What have I already tried:**

1-) Since my network is behind a proxy, I've added the proxy credentials through NPM configuration commands. ([as can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043154/11858000))
(I also set the `strict-ssl` to `false`).

2-) Since it didn't do anything, I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15463892/11858000) method and edited the global `nuget.config` file. But didn't solve any problem.

3-) I tried [this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10295) too, but setting the environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` seems to do nothing about my problem.

My PATH variable has these:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet`,
`%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`

I also downloaded the latest Dotnet 5.0 SDK and installed it, but nothing.

---

Only command that works with `dotnet` is the `--list-sdks` command which shows this result:

[image]

Comment: Can you try it from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt instead of powershell to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @dcp Same behavior continues over there as well. I also contacted other people from my team and none of them has this problem, so there's that too.

Comment: I would consider running a repair or reinstall of Visual Studio since something seems to be messed up with your installation.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work :/

Comment: Apologies, but I don't have any other ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled all the .NET SDKs and runtimes, I also removed all the installed modules on both VS 2019 and VS 2022 Preview using the Visual Studio Installer, then restarted my computer.

While installing the SDKs and runtimes from [Microsoft's website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) I checked the .NET version using the command line and command `dotnet --version` after every installation to see when exactly it starts not working. After installing all the SDK's up to .NET 5, there was no issue. And since I did not really need the .NET 6 SDK I didn't specifically download it thinking VS 2022 Preview would automatically install it anyways.

Using Visual Studio Installer, I installed the necessary components for the dotnet development on the VS 2019 and the previously mentioned command was working on point. Then I proceeded to install the necessary components on the VS 2022 Preview but after installing it, the command started to not work. So there it was, the **source** of the problem. Something about VS 2022 Preview's installment process just corrupts dotnet cli, but I'm not sure if it's just me.

You also need a restart after all the installments or dotnet cli might show some errors.