# How do we install the Nuget packages in client's machine if there is no internet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

We need to install the Nuget packages if client's machine does not have internet.

Client informed us to install Nuget packages through Proxy. So they have shared Proxy URL and credentials and certificates.

We would like to know how to install the Nuget packages through Proxy and share here with syntax for installing Nuget thru commands.

We modified the Nuget config file as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ves3.png)

Then execute the below command in Package console, getting the below errors in the screen shots.

NuGet\Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 13.0.3

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OVBz.png)

Pls let us know how to install nuget packages in client's machine thru commands with Proxy only.

Comment: Looking at the documentation the password for the proxy uses http_proxy.password not ClearTextPassword which you have used. The documentation also mentions that the password needs to be encrypted. NuGet documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section StackOverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-a-proxy