# elmah causes application crash

Tags: asp.net, crash, elmah

Has anyone else run into an issue where Elmah has caused application crashes?  On one of my site this was definately the case but I had been using it for a long time beforehand and never had this problem.  Now another site that uses it has had application crashes.

Comment: Is it happening on local pc or when deploying on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ELMAH 1.1 or 1.2, verify that you're packaging all of the referenced DLLs needed in order to persist to your data store. Also make sure that you're using the right version of the x64/x86 libraries.

I ran into a similar issue when I was storing my data in SQLite. It was quite a while ago, but it ended up being something about the dlls not being compiled in a compatible way.

My fix ended up being completely upgrading to the newest version of ELMAH (once I did that, my issue went away).

[This post may also be relevant...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite/11232395#11232395)