# Get error during build. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have build error after I move my classes to Class Project. I know this is caused by Elmah but I not sure what's wrong.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Normally this error occur in IIS if configured the wrong platform. But now I can't even build the website. FYI, I have set the Build Platform to x86.

Comment: Is System.Data.SQLLite referenced in your new class project?  If your original project referenced it and you moved that code to the class project, then the class project will need to reference it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause. I referenced it in my new Class Project but removed it in the Website project. After I added the "System.Data.SQLite" reference in both Class Project & website project. It works !