# ELMAH Not working, Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I am trying to get Elmah error handling working and followed the following tutorial to get it up and running:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC

The error message i get is the following:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Comment: add the assembly into references...

Comment: @AndréGadonski I Added the reference to emlah, i followed the tutorial step by step.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite