# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I am trying to use 64-bit `Sqlite` on my `Aspx` project. When I run the project, I got the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Data.Sqlite’ or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

I even set the `Enable 32-Bit Aplications` to `True` to fix the problem, but the issue still persists. I am using `.Net 4 Framework`. I even downloaded `64-bit SQlite .dll` and included it in my project and still it didn’t solve my problem. What can I do to resolve this?

Since I couldn't post the image. I am posting the error logs

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = SANZ\Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.SQLite
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Data.SQLite | Domain ID: 36
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/StoneCarving/StoneCarving/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\StoneCarving\StoneCarving\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\StoneCarving\StoneCarving\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/c78c2519/83a165be/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/c78c2519/83a165be/System.Data.SQLite/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/StoneCarving/StoneCarving/bin/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +618
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +209
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +94
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +332
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +591

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8946484
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258
```

Comment: Are you compiling your program specifically to 64 bits? If not, whenever you run it in 32 bits you'll get this error.

Comment: What version of IIS are you hosting in?

Comment: Pasting your question title into Google reveals this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite. Likely, your question is a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not use NuGet or prefer to reference the sqlite assemblies your self, make sure you use the right platform version (x64 vs x86).

To support both platform, you can reference the System.Data.SQLite.dll, and adds 2 separate folders for each platform to hold the SQLite.Interop.dl.

Copy from official sqlite download site:

- bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
- bin\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
- bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)

With this setup, your app can run in both x64 and x86 platform. 
For more detail info, you can refer to sqlite download site [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Answer (score 8):

**Nuget** was the final solution for me, i was using x64 because i have windows 8.1 64 bit,However **i should use x86**. once install **System.Data.SQLite**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio try installing through the package manager http://www.nuget.org/packages/system.data.sqlite. This may help out with the dependency tree issues.