# Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1) binding error in release mode

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am using the setup from sqlite.org:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.94.0.exe

Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1)

My application is set up to use framework 4.5.1. 
"Prefer 32 bit" is not checked.

During Debug Mode, it runs flawlessly.

However, when I switch to Release Mode, I am getting this error:
"BindingFailure" detected at "D:\Dev\Projects\MyProject\AppNet\MyApp\MyApp\Release\MyApp.vshost.exe"" festgestellt.

The assembly "System.Data.SQLite" could not be loaded in AppDomain1 in the binding context of "Load":
System.BadImageFormatException: The file or assembly "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" or one of its dependencies was not found.

Can somebody tell me how I should do differently?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the reference (in VS project explorer right click the SQLite reference library) and added again? It happened sometimes if the reference is pointed to a wrong one (unreachable folder or...).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that now, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my question is a duplicate of 
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

In this post, there was no real answer but just the suggestion to use x86.

However, I think that this is only a workaround, not a real solution, because the SQLITE binaries are clearly marked 32bit and 64 bit, and I have chose then correct assemblies.