# Sql lite connection Error

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

connection string am using

```
 SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=F:\\Game\\GameBKS\\Game_Latest\\GameNew\\exe.BKS.s3db;Version=3;FailIfMissing=false;New=True;Compress=True;Synchronous=Off");
```

Comment: Did you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite?rq=1

Comment: It is an windows application

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite library contains/interacts with (depending on which version you are using) a native SQLite library, and these are platform-specific.

The message below indicates that the library is incompatible with the mode your application is currently running in:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

You can change the target platform in the project properties -> build -> platform target combobox. If you downloaded the x86 version of the library, your project must also be compiled for x86 specifically.