# System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) at

Tags: sqlite, outlook

I am getting following error when running the application.

System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at ReserveOutlookIntegration.TririgaComm..cctor() in C:\dev\iss-outlook-plugin\AddIn2010\TririgaComm.cs:line 85
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ReserveOutlookIntegration.TririgaComm.getInstance() in C:\dev\iss-outlook-plugin\AddIn2010\TririgaComm.cs:line 96
   at OutlookPropertyPage.TriOptionPage..ctor(PlugInProperties properties) in C:\dev\iss-outlook-plugin\AddIn2010\OutlookOptionPage\TriOptionPage.cs:line 43
   at ReserveOutlookIntegration.ThisAddIn.Application_OptionsPagesAdd(PropertyPages Pages) in C:\dev\iss-outlook-plugin\AddIn2010\ThisAddIn.cs:line 106

We have Outlook plugin developed for Room reservation manager.

The previous versions of plugin was working perfectly alright in Windows 7. Currently the same versions stopped working in Windows 10 and we have .NET framework version above 4.0 in the all systems.

The SQLite versions in my development environment is 1.0.109.0.

Kindly suggest. I am lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

Comment: If you try to run 32-bit applications on IIS 7 (and/or 64-bit OS machine), you will get the same error. You could refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626562/system-badimageformatexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-in

Comment: Hi Simon, the link provided by you points to my problem page.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Here is the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p