# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.115.5

Tags: sqlite, exception, assemblies, system.data.sqlite, .net-4.8

.NET Framework project - added SQLite to my project via Nuget package, app.config and package.config look correct.

Errors is:-
"Type : System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.115.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139**' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

All projects targeting x86

Packages.config

```
<packages>
   <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net471" />
   <package id="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework" version="1.0.115.5" targetFramework="net471" />
   <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.115.5" targetFramework="net471" />
   <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.115.5" targetFramework="net471" />
   <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.115.5" targetFramework="net471" />
   <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.115.5" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

I have tried links below and so many others but nothing working - what am I missing?

[Could not load file](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=f81eca75-98a6-42e6-abb1-48d6f022bddc)

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

[image]

Comment: Which version is actually in your bin folder? This typically happens if you have multiple projects linking different versions of the Sqlite nuget.

Comment: @PMF It has the correct version - updated my post to include the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem when I upgraded from 1.0.113 to 1.0.115. It appears that the dependent native binaries are not correctly copied any more.

Adding these two lines to the post build step of a project (doesn't really matter which one in your solution) helped:

```
xcopy /s /y "%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact\4.0.8876.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
xcopy /s /y "%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework\1.0.115\build\net46\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

(Maybe you need to adapt the lines, depending on the package version used and the .NET version targeted)

**EDIT**
Since you are still using packages.config, the above copy instructions should probably be changed to:

```
xcopy /s /y "$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact\4.0.8876.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
xcopy /s /y "$(SolutionDir)\packages\Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework\1.0.115\build\net46\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works...

Comment: I added the last line - ( we are removing SQLserver.Compact ) and the same error persists...

Comment: Do you have a file named `SQLite.Interop.dll` in your bin folder or a subfolder of it?

Comment: Only in the packages folder

Comment: Oh, I just see that you're still using `packages.config`. Then you need to adapt the copy steps. You basically need to cpy the two files `x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` and `x64\SQLite.Interop.dll` from the `Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework` package to your bin directory.