# Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) version 1.0.115.5. I am attempting to create and open a SQLiteConnection as follows.

```
string DatabaseName = GetDatabasePath();
var sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={DatabaseName}");
sqlite2.Open();
```

GetDatabasePath is a function that returns the full path to the DB file.

I am getting the following exception.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.115.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=433d9874d0bb98c5, processorArchitecture=MSIL'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Based on my research System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License is part of the SQLite Encryption Extension. It is used if you want to create a password for the database. Howevever, I am not using a password for the database. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Try using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite instead.

Comment: What exactly does GetDatabasePath return?

Comment: @AnonCoward GetDatabasePath is a function that returns the full path to the DB file.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?

Comment: @ramaral I now use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite instead.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite has some [drawbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/compare)

Comment: The answer to this question helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite?rq=1, Switch from running x86 to Any CPU / x64 and it worked for me. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

im got same error like you.
I'm also not doing any encryption on the database.
So I think this should actually be a bug of System.Data.SQLite.Core itself.

you need update System.Data.SQLite.Core ver  from  1.0.115.5 to 1.0.116

It should be noted that the version you finally reference may be determined by the version of the third-party library. For example, I encountered this problem.
this is my reason
https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite/issues/46