# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version =1.0.117.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, c#-2.0, system.data.sqlite

I am facing error with window form application with .net framework. I have successfully built a SQLite database through application but when I am going to update the database it give me below error.

> System.I0. FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> "System.Data.SOLite.SEE.License, Version = 1.0.1 17.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken-433d9874d0bb98c5' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the specified.

I am wondering why this is giving me error beside that this database created by same file path.

I tried different versions of SQLite NuGet packages and .net framework but hadn't got luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257247/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite-see-license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use password connection string? This is a common reason. The password connection string property relies on the legacy CryptoAPI codec. And this module code has been unmaintained since 2011, and it is no longer supported in 2017, and it cannot run at all since version 1.0.113.0.
If you use a version earlier than 1.0.113.0, this issue will be resolved.

But if this doesn't work for you please provide more information.

**Update：**

[System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.2.nupkg](https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.112.0/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.2.nupkg)

Comment: Exactly, I’m using string as password. Will it work if I use int. Secondly, could you please tell me how I can get old version before 1.0.113.0

Comment: @MUHAMMADATHERFAROOQ The principle of the password link of string and int is very close, you need to try it in the version before [1.0.113.0](https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.112.0/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.2.nupkg)

Comment: Thank you dear, I installed 1.0.112.0 version, and it is working for me.

Comment: how to installed 1.0.112.0 version ? where NuGet packages and .net framework but hadn't

MUHAMMAD ATHER FAROOQ