# Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have a problem here while i was trying to make a project in Visual Studio with ASP.NET Web Application project template
So when i tried to start debugging, it returns an error while i haven't change any template yet. can anyone help me what happen here? cause i'm still new here and  also just installed a certificate from a certification authority that was told to when i click start debugging before

Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'coba4' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +102
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +307
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'coba4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10072388
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer of this problem.

It turns out that the folder name that references to my project contains space and ;D .

I don't know which one make the problems, but I've just changed it into a normal folder name and it turns out great!